# I can't get my collision detection between an Object and Picture Box to work C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, object, collision-detection, collision

Here is the code that deals with the pink fish object and the collision. The collision is detected as I used a message box to find if the collision was being detected but when i changed it back to changing the visibility nothing happens

```
    private PinkFish[] myPinkFish = new PinkFish[4];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //for loops to place the objects into the form
        for (int i = 0; i < myPinkFish.Length; ++i)
        {
            myPinkFish[i] = new PinkFish(this);
        }

    //timer to allow movement 
    private void movementTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

           //for loops for movement of pink fish object
            for (int i = 0; i < myPinkFish.Length; ++i)
            {
                myPinkFish[i].move();
            }

            //collision detection between the pink fish and moving cat
            if (movingCatPic.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PinkFish.pinkFish.Bounds))
            {
                PinkFish.pinkFish.visible = false;
            }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you are saying that `PinkFish.pinkFish.visible = false;` does not work then the problem is not about collision detection, but about something else. We cannot possibly know about what, because we don't see any relevant code.

Comment: So the problem is with the object I am trying to make invisible rather than my collision?

What code would be relevant? the Pink fish class?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know your code. You know your code, so you should investigate the problem.